# Unable to load Python library into AWS Glue Spark job

Tags: python, aws-glue

I need to `import jaydebeapi` in my AWS Glue Spark job (Glue version 3.0). `jaydebeapi` depends on `JPype1`. So I downloaded the following two wheel files and put them in an S3 bucket. I then reference these two files in the Job Details as following, under `Python Library Path`:

```
s3://my_bucket/whl/JPype1-1.4.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl,s3://my_bucket/whl/JayDeBeApi-1.2.3-py3-none-any.whl
```

When running the job, I still see this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_jpype'
```

How would I fix this?